# creating an array of strings with predefined length in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management

I want to make an array of 20 strings (`char*`) where each of them is allocated automatically length of `MAXLENGTH`

will by saying:

```
char *string_arr[MAXLENGTH][20];
```

I'll be able to address each string as `string_arr[i]` where `0=<i<20` and more importantly, will I be able to put things into `string_arr[i]` without dynamically allocating memory, e.g:

```
strcpy(string_arr[2],"some string");
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
char *string_arr[MAXLENGTH][20];
```

Say:

```
char string_arr[20][MAXLENGTH];
```

You also probably want to say `MAXLENGTH+1` for null termination.